I’m trying to create an either/ or formula using the IF function but having limited success
I am trying to display the content of A1 or A2 in cell C1 using Column B as a check box. So far I have this but need something else to get A2 to display if chosen.
=IF(B1<>"", A1, "")

It’s an either or result I’m looking for.

The "or" value is the third parameter of IF(), that you currently have as just an empty string.  Put A2 there instead.

The question doesn't mention what spreadsheet application you are using, but the IF statement is pretty standard for several popular spreadsheets, such as Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets.
When using Google Sheets, a checkbox might be a data validation set that is displayed as a checkbox. The in-kind checkbox by default, could return one of three values

Unchecked: Blanck or FALSE unless it's customized.
Checked: TRUE unless it's customized.

If B1 has a checkbox set to use the default values for checked and unchecked states, the following formula will work:
=IF(B1, A1, A2)

Note: A blank cell is parsed as FALSE when used in a comparison expression and as the first argument of the IF function.

I’m using Google Sheets. Sorry

That doesn’t return A2 if it’s B2 that’s checked. If both checkboxes are blank, I need C 1 to be blank.

@DaveTaylor your question states you are checking B1, but your comment now states B2. So a simple construct might be to check both B1 and B2 like "and(b1<>"",B2<>"")" but "or(and(b1<>"",B2<>"")" may be relevant, however without a clear explanation of what cells you are testing...

@DaveTaylor The formula works perfectly on my spreadsheet. Please post a new question providing enough details to reproduce your context. Include the spreadsheet locale/country. This is relevant as it determines the function parameter separator ( a comma or a semicolon). Also, the sample values for A1 and A2 should be included for completeness and to eliminate further back and forth.

To add clarification, in column A I have two teams. One in A 1 and the other in A2.. Beside each team is a check box in column b indicating which won the game. The checkboxes are in B1 and B2 respectively. The winner goes on to play and it’s displayed in C1.

@Dave, In a previous comment, I suggested you post a new question. I don't know if you already this. If you haven't please do it and include on it all the relevant details.
